# Detectar la tecla enter en php

Tags: jquery, datatables, php7

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente duda este es parte del codigo que estoy utilizando con un plugin datatable

```
$botones =  "<div class='btn-group'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary agregarProducto 
             recuperarBoton' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."'>Agregar</button></div>"; 

        $datosJson .='[
              "'.($i+1).'",
              "'.$imagen.'",
              "'.$productos[$i]["codigo"].'",
              "'.$productos[$i]["descripcion"].'",
              "'.$stock.'",
              "'.$botones.'"
            ],';
```

y esta es otra parte del codigo donde aplico un console.log para ver si me trae el id

```
$(".tablaVentas tbody").on("click", "button.agregarProducto",function(){

    var idProducto = $(this).attr("idProducto");

    console.log("idProducto", idProducto);
});
```

Esta es la imagen de que cuando hago click en el boton agregar me trae el id de forma correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora mi pregunta es como deberia hacer para que presionando enter en el teclado me traiga el resultado ,intente con un keypress pero no tuve resultado quizas algo estoy haciendo mal ya que recien estoy empezando a programar .Desde ya muchas  gracias

Answer (score 0):

necesitaras hacerlo a nivel de documento te lo dejo puesto en javascript para que puedas revisar como capturo los eventos

```js
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 77) {
    alert("M key was pressed");
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 66) {
    alert("Ctrl + B shortcut combination was pressed");
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.which == 89) {
    alert("Ctrl + Alt + Y shortcut combination was pressed");
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.which == 85) {
    alert("Ctrl + Alt + Shift + U shortcut combination was pressed");
  } else if (e.keyCode || e.which == 13) {
    alert("enter");
  }
};
```

```html
<h3>Press M key on keyboard(Single key)</h3>
<h3>Press Ctrl + B shortcut key (Double key combination)</h3>
<h3>Press Ctrl + Alt + Y shortcut key (Multiple key combination)</h3>
<h3>Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + U shortcut key (Multiple key combination)</h3>
<h3>Press enter</h3>
```

Recuerda que tienes que estar con el focus dentro del documento de este ejemplo al ser un snippet (darle click dentro del html del ejemplo)